# HTTP Error 500 displayed when i try logging into my website

Tags: php, http, web, html

I am making a simple login page for a test site i am trying to make. Every time I try logging in with the hard coded password it gives me an HTTP 500 error which means that I have misspelled something but I can seem to find what the problem is as everything seems fine.

This is the log-in.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
    session_start();

    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true){
        header("Location: success.php");       
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password){

            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
            header("Location: success.php");
        }

    }
?>

<html>
        <body>
            <form method="post" action="log-in.php">
                Username:<br/>
                <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
                Password<br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Login!">
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I want to display when the correct password is inputted. This is the success.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == false){
        header("Location: index.html")
    }
?>

<html>
<h>You have logged in!</h>

</html>
```

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Are you positive it is a spelling error? HTTP 500 errors are pretty generic by themselves, just an "Internal Server Error"? How do you know that it is indeed a spelling error?

Comment: `session_start();` must be at the very top of the page before a single byte is rendered. No whitespace or carriage returns. If you got a 500 error there should be something in your error log (assuming your php.ini is setup with error reporting)

Comment: Check your server logs, and/or activate error display.

Comment: I found it. You are missing a semicolon after `header("Location: index.html")` in the `success.php`. Use error reporting so you don't have to come to SO to fix simple errors. They will tell you which line you need to check.

Comment: a semicolon is missing after header("Location: index.html")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semicolon left at line 6 in success.php.

Semicolon is must in php otherwise it causes error 500.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == false){
        header("Location: index.html")
    }
?>

<html>
<h>You have logged in!</h>

</html>
```

should be changed to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == false){
        header("Location: index.html");//semicolon added
    }
?>

<html>
<h>You have logged in!</h>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` , you can't header redirect after sending output to the browser.

Comment: This shouldn't result in a HTTP 500.